# How can I see the list of all mails I received, regardless of which folder they are located in, in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I can see all mails in a given folder in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA) (https://outlook.office365.com/owa/) by clicking on the folder.

Is there a way to view all messages across all folders at the same time?

For example, in Gmail, one can see all mails in all folders by clicking on "All Mail":

[image]

Does the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA) offer something similar? I tried to look for some "all mails" option in OWA but I didn't find it.

---

I understand that a message in Outlook OWA cannot be in two folders. I'm asking about showing all emails regardless of what folder they reside in.. I sounds like Blindspot are saying that this can only be done with a search option? In which case, what's the search option to show all emails from all folders?

I also understand that in Gmail, Gmail doesn't use folders. Instead, it uses labels, and with labels, an email could have multiple labels. But my question stands in regard to folders in Outlook.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146947/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-see-all-mails-in-the-micr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Outlook 'All Mail' Folder

To save a predefined search in Outlook that includes all messages across all folders, similar to Gmail's [All Mail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all), requires creating a **Search Folder**.

### Outlook Search Folders

Search Folders are virtual folders in Outlook that provide a view of all email items matching specific search criteria even though the messages might be saved in different folders across a mailbox.

### Must first be created in Outlook

You can't currently create Search Folders directly in Outlook Web, they must be created in Outlook Desktop and then synced to Outlook Web.  It appears that this functionality is evolving and native support in Outlook Web may be added in the future.

### Resources

- [Use Search Folders to find messages or other Outlook items](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5)
- [Search Folders created in Outlook do not appear in Outlook Web Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/search-folders-created-in-outlook-do-not-appear-in-owa)
- **Outlook Roadmap:**

  - Feature ID 122152: [Outlook for Windows and web, support for search folders](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/roadmap?featureid=122152)
  - Feature ID 151025: [Outlook Folder/Subfolder Recursive Search](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/roadmap?featureid=151025)
- **Learn  Microsoft Exchange:**

  - [Folders and items in EWS in Exchange #Search Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/folders-and-items-in-ews-in-exchange#search-folders)